# How to concatenate more fields in one textbox separated by "/" in Telerik reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik-reporting

I want to know how to concatenate more fields in one text box in Telerik reporting separated by "/" in expression of text box.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Value` of a text box, you can use expressions to concatenate multiple fields.  You can do it with plain expressions such as:

```
=Fields.FirstField + '/' + Fields.SecondField
```

or you can use embedded expressions:

```
{Fields.FirstFIeld}/{Fields.SecondField}
```

You can see their documentation for more information about [expressions](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-property-values.html) and [embedded expressions](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-embedded.html).

Comment: It will display blank line if any of the fields contain a null value.

Comment: So you may need to use `IsNull(Fields.SecondField, 'replacement_value')`